# Georeferencing of image (like Google Floor Plans)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a building floor plan and I need to specify its position on top of google map.

I like the way this is done in Google Floor Plans app - [screenshot](http://screencloud.net/img/screenshots/3d973ba1b3541a403fef0f3ffe7fcdd9.png)(the right part with map) - but I cannot figure out how they made it! :)

What part in Google Maps API I should look at?

In short - I have an image (plan of floor), and need to show it on top of Google Map and be able to manipulate with it (changing dimensions on events).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Cianan Sims: Well, sure, I want custom overlay, but how is the question :-)

Fortunately, Google published tool called [Overlay Tiler](https://code.google.com/p/overlay-tiler/), which does exactly what I wanted - georeferencing of the image.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you'll want to implement a [custom overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays). That link provides the relevant instructions for doing so. Also, Google provides a simple example so you can see the result [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple). Is that sort of what you're going for?