# Treat a floor plan like Google Maps

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, draw

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC5 indoor and outdoor localization project.
For the outdoor localization I used Google Maps and can show the map with a marker and a radius that is the accuracy of the position.

[image]

For the indoor localization I'm using an Texas Instruments iBeacon that sends via bluetooth MAJ, MIN and distance from it self to my smartphone that sends an SMS so I can get the informations to the server. Now I'm trying to get the same result of the map but instead of the map a draw of the room where the iBeacon is placed and put a marker with a circle.

Something like this:

[image]

I'd like to set the iBeacon position and draw a circle around it.

Thank you

Comment: Use paint to draw a picture of your room?

Comment: Yes, I did.
But after displaying the floor plan how can I dinamically put the marker and the circle?
I've also downloaded the marker image.

Comment: you way want to look at http://leafletjs.com/ which allows you to use custom images as map tiles or this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180115/georeferencing-of-image-like-google-floor-plans

Comment: @MajoB: the maps-API also supports custom tiles(mapTypes) : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#ImageMapTypes